# python migrate data from one dict into another dict using a template

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to migrate the data from a dict into another dict for which I have a template.

Original dict:

```py
persons = {
    'names': ['Greg', 'Milla', 'Paul', 'Linda'],
    'ages': [43, 24, 55, 14],
}
```

Template dict:

```py
persons_template = {
    'data': {
        'name': '',
        'age': '',
    }
}
```

Migration script:

```py
persons_new = {}
for idx, name in enumerate(persons['names']):
    person = persons_template
    person['data']['name'] = persons['names'][idx]
    person['data']['age'] = persons['ages'][idx]
    print(person)
    persons_new[idx] = person
persons_new
```

The executed code results as follows:

```py
{'data': {'name': 'Greg', 'age': 43}}
{'data': {'name': 'Milla', 'age': 24}}
{'data': {'name': 'Paul', 'age': 55}}
{'data': {'name': 'Linda', 'age': 14}}

{0: {'data': {'name': 'Linda', 'age': 14}},
 1: {'data': {'name': 'Linda', 'age': 14}},
 2: {'data': {'name': 'Linda', 'age': 14}},
 3: {'data': {'name': 'Linda', 'age': 14}}}
```

The first output from the print statement shows correctly the data sets.
The second output shows the new dict "persons_new". I can't figure out why "persons_new" only has the last data set from the original dict?

Thanks and regards,
carlo

Comment: That is due to the named reference, I believe.
Try printing `persons_template` as well at each iteration, you'll know what's going wrong

Comment: @ThePyGuy thanks for the tip! That's weird, when I print persons_template it seems that it's getting overwritten in every loop. Why does the for loop change the template dict?

Answer (score 2):

`person = person_template` doesn't do what you think it does. You're binding `person` to the same underlying dictionary that `person_template` is bound to. You're not making a copy or anything. Any changes you apply to `person` will also be applied to `person_template`, and vice-versa.

Alternatively, the `dict` built-in accepts a collection of tuples, which will be unpacked into key-value pairs. If you write a generator that yields key-value tuples, your dictionary can be generated in the following way:

```
def generate_dict():
    for index, (name, age) in enumerate(zip(persons["names"], persons["ages"])):
        yield index, {
            "data": {
                "name": name,
                "age": age
            }
        }

persons_new = dict(generate_dict())
print(persons_new)
```

Output:

```
{0: {'data': {'name': 'Greg', 'age': 43}}, 1: {'data': {'name': 'Milla', 'age': 24}}, 2: {'data': {'name': 'Paul', 'age': 55}}, 3: {'data': {'name': 'Linda', 'age': 14}}}
>>>
```

Comment: That's also a very nice solution! Very cool, and thanks for the explanations, now I understand the underlying problem!

Answer (score 1):

That is due to the named reference. Try printing `persons_template` as well at each iteration, you'll know what's going wrong.
Basically, what happens is, when you use assignment `=` operators for sequence, Python creates a named reference instead of creating a separate copy, in your case, `person` is also making reference to the same memory location as `persons_template`. You can verify this printing `person is persons_template` inside the loop.
To illustrate it, you can try something like:

```py
x = (2,3,)
y = x
x is y
Out[127]: True
```

Or

```py
x = {'a':1}
y = x
y is x
Out[128]: True
```

To avoid that, you can copy the dictionary to another variable using `copy.deepcopy`

Modified version:

```py
import copy
persons_new = {}
for idx, name in enumerate(persons['names']):
    person = copy.deepcopy(persons_template)
    person['data']['name'] = persons['names'][idx]
    person['data']['age'] = persons['ages'][idx]
    print(person)
    persons_new[idx] = copy.deepcopy(person)
persons_new
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
{'data': {'name': 'Greg', 'age': 43}}
{'data': {'name': 'Milla', 'age': 24}}
{'data': {'name': 'Paul', 'age': 55}}
{'data': {'name': 'Linda', 'age': 14}}
Out[124]: 
{0: {'data': {'name': 'Greg', 'age': 43}},
 1: {'data': {'name': 'Milla', 'age': 24}},
 2: {'data': {'name': 'Paul', 'age': 55}},
 3: {'data': {'name': 'Linda', 'age': 14}}}
```

Comment: That's doing the trick, thank you very much! However, I don't understand why python needs that deepcopy here. Do you know the underlying concept there? Just to learn when I need to apply it in the future...

Comment: See the updated answer. You can search for `python named reference` to know more

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referencing `person` every time you iterate, the value of person updates itself every time, and you end up with 4 references in your dictionary to the final version of person, i.e. Linda.

If you want to copy the values from the dictionary, you can use the following:

```
from copy import deepcopy

persons_new = {}

for idx, name in enumerate(persons['names']):
    person = persons_template
    person['data']['name'] = persons['names'][idx]
    person['data']['age'] = persons['ages'][idx]
    print(person)
    persons_new[idx] = deepcopy(person)
persons_new
```

This should give you the result you expect:

```
{'data': {'name': 'Greg', 'age': 43}}
{'data': {'name': 'Milla', 'age': 24}}
{'data': {'name': 'Paul', 'age': 55}}
{'data': {'name': 'Linda', 'age': 14}}
{0: {'data': {'name': 'Greg', 'age': 43}},
 1: {'data': {'name': 'Milla', 'age': 24}},
 2: {'data': {'name': 'Paul', 'age': 55}},
 3: {'data': {'name': 'Linda', 'age': 14}}}
```